# jQuery replaceWith() with an external php generated footer

Tags: php, jquery, html

essentially i have this function that simply takes a variable that i want to then replace a specific  with that variable.

JQUERY

```
function updateCart(new_total)
    {
        var total = new_total;
        var content = $("#replaceme");
        content.replaceWith("<h1>hello</h1>");

        alert(content.html());
    }
```

PHP

```
echo "<div id='replaceme'><span id='checkout-summary'>" . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name1] . " Item | $" . $total . "</span></div>";
```

i am not sure why this is not working, like i mentioned before the php is included as footer.php and the html is generated by use of an echo statement but i do not see how this should make any difference to the jQuery function as the page does load and also when i test to see if the correct div is being selected by alert(content.html()); i successfully get the content of #replaceme

any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

to show that i know how to use this function, this following code test i work wrote, just not in the my other use case

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var content = $("#checkout-summary");
        content.replaceWith("<h1>hello</h1>");
        //$("#checkout-summary").after("<h1>hello</h1>").remove();
        console.log(content.html());
    });
```

Comment: how do call your function? on DOM ready?

Comment: i call it on submit of a form. @ali

Comment: It works on mine. Do you see any error in javascript console?

Comment: nope nothing at all in the console @ali, it is a jQuery Mobile structure site so potentially some conflict there? it's weird because when log the content.html() it's succesfully finding that div.

Comment: Do you see the alert but the content is not updating?

Comment: yes i see the alert with the correct content but the content is not being replaced. so the .replaceWith() is not correctly functioning. @ali

Comment: as a suggestion apply hide() on #replaceme and apply show() on desired element.

Comment: content.hide(); also does not change anything visually @ali

Comment: After you replace element with a new element, **.after** wont work any more. the single line that includes **.after** is enough for all of your proposes.

Comment: yes you are right, but replaceWith(); is not working regardless so it works, but you are right if it was working the last code snippet probably wouldnt work, or the last line before the alert() would be pointless

Comment: <script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#checkout-summary").after("h1>hello</h1>").remove();})</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why but i had to essentially change

```
$("#replaceme").replaceWith("<h1>hello</h1>")
```

with

```
$("div#replaceme").replaceWith("<h1>hello</h1>")
```

i guess moral is be as specific as possible.

Comment: Any chance you had the same id more than once?

Answer (score 0):

It works on pc. If you have issue with mobile use this alternative:

```
$("#replaceme").after("<h1>hello</h1>").remove();
```

Comment: Are you sure you are including jquery in your project? :D

Comment: i can get it to work just not in my specific application, and yes i use it extensively throughout my project I've updated my post to see show that i can successfully use the what I'm trying to do just not in my wanted way.

Comment: Do you use exact code you pasted here? what is **new_total** so?

Comment: it's what i am going to use to replace it with instead of hello, i removed it from the example above because it obviously is not doing anything. yes i essentially use the exact same code except that instead of all the html being generated in one html document it is generated with an external php footer.

Comment: You might  have error placing that parameter in your code. How do you place it?

Comment: <?php printFooter(1) ?> || where 1 is a selector for which type of footer i have different footers with different text. so its a php function included in the bottom of my html doc before the closing </body> tag of course. the function basically echoes html tags like <div>'s and such